# "No such file or directory - getcwd" error on rubygems on Mac Os Lion

Tags: macos, rubygems, heroku

I'm trying to launch a [heroku console](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/console) that uses rubygems but I keep getting this error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:471:in `expand_path': No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:471:in `find_files'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:470:in `map'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:470:in `find_files'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1103
    from /usr/bin/heroku:9:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/heroku:9
```

I'm using Mac OS Lion 10.7.3. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I had that same issue.... running `sudo gem update --system` fixed the problem... give it a try.

Comment: Works for me too on my Ubuntu VPS. What exactly gets fixed by doing this?

Comment: it don't fixed for me

Comment: Can you explain what does this do?

Answer (score 166):

Maybe the current working directory of the shell that's used to start your heroku process doesn't exist (maybe removed by another process, as in my case), and therefore getcwd throws an error.

Comment: +1 ... This error is also thrown if you have left a shell open in a deleted/moved directory locally and try to run anything with Bundler.

Comment: Was in a directory removed from underneath me during a puppet run.

Comment: This was my error. I deleted a github repo and cloned down a directory with exactly the same name. Everything appeared to work, until this error come. Changing out of the directory and changing back into it helped a lot.

Comment: This should be the real answer right here. Thanks! :)

Comment: This helped me, I was in a network mapped drive through sshfs. Changing to a directory on the local machine worked.

Comment: Thanks. I had an old rails server running. Once I closed out of that it fixed the issue

Comment: Because of an old server, I'm running old versions of `ruby` and `gem`, so I won't go submitting a bug report, but I sure hope they've put in a sane error message for this by now in current versions of ruby.

Comment: u are right, i change to another directory, it is resolved

Answer (score 61):

This happened to me. It turned out I had deleted the folder I was running the command in.

Comment: Ah. yes. I forgot I deleted the folder where I running the command.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same thing, just type `cd` in the terminal, then navigate back to where you were and it works.

Comment: you should be in the root directory of your rails app. That fixed for me.

Answer (score 13):

Tried starting the rails server in another console tab.

`cd .` solved it for me

Comment: Solved for me as well! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

Faced a similar issue while setting up rails app locally.

The issue was that the server was running in a directory which i had removed from another terminal window to recreate the app.

Close terminal and do it again or go to some other directory and come back and do it...

Anything should work..It did for me.

Answer (score 4):

I encounter a same one, it happened when the working directory has actually been removed.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't appear to be Heroku issue as something in your code is requiring this `getcwd`.

What happens if you run this application locally in production mode?  Have you defined all of your dependencies for Heroku (either [via a .gems file or Bundler](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/gems))

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was in a directory that had "unusual" characters in its name: `/Volumes/Members/Finance & Accounting/-MC 2008, 7848/2020`.

And also, I was in a remote directory, as Mac users will recognize.

I simply did `push ~` and ran the command again, then did `popd` to get back to my remote directory with odd characters in the name.

It could be that `gem` is ill-behaved in the face of directory names containing whitespace, or it could be that it doesn't work on networked directories.

The bash built-in `pwd` worked just fine in the remote directory with the funny name.

This whole thing makes me a bit nervous about `gem`.

Answer (score 1):

solved for me

```
cd ..
cd -
```

you have to go back and return to current directory.

Comment: Strange! Thanks for sharing, It got fixed!

Comment: could also just do: `cd - && cd -`

Answer (score 1):

Ended up on this page from searching for the same error on AWS Elastic beanstalk.

The problem with getcwd is because EB is trying to repeat the deployment process endlessly. It changes the /var/app/staging directory before it is able to finish the current action. getcwd fails because the directory was already replaced. Try deploying a stable version or a sample app

Answer (score 0):

[as explained by gerardk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243548/no-such-file-or-directory-getcwd-error-on-rubygems-on-mac-os-lion/9375700#9375700)
you could try this before launching back heroku console

```
$ pwd #ie: /mywork
$ cd ..
$ cd [pwd] #ie: cd mywork
```

now go launch back heroku console

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me while I was running a Sinatra app on my localhost and this is what I found.

Scenario:
I'm using Git as my version control and I switched branches from development to master to merge my branches. After the merge, with an active server running, I made a minor html change which shouldn't have blown up the app and when I went to check the change in my broswer my "request" came back with OP's error - just to note this app isn't deployed to heroku.

My guess:
I'm not familiar with the intricacies of Webbrick (or equivalent programs) but I'm guessing you had an active server running (like me) and it was was looking for specific file(s) in memory and when they were modified on a possible branch change or an important file was modified/deleted - Webbrick freaked out and didn't know where to find it/them and threw up this error.

I'm not sure what version control you're using but I know git is popular for heroku so I think this might have something to do with your issue.

Fixing the issue for myself was as simple as restarting the server, hope this helps future trouble shooters.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by closing and restarting my terminal, setting the correct Ruby version in the new Terminal to

```
$ rvm use 2.1.1
```

(or whatever Ruby version is relevant to your program)

Answer (score 0):

Restart system fixed this problem in my case

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this error by shutting down the server, restarting my terminal, then restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo gem update --system` (as [Israfil Havilah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9549529/2394732) mentioned) and rebooting the server (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS) helped me

Answer (score -1):

Make sure, you are not switching git branches. To me, it happened due to switching between GIT branches deleted my folder.