# Error after installing devise in rails

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I installed devise for rails 4 and followed all the necessary instructions.

I have the root 'home/index'. 
In my home/index view erb is the following.

`<%= link_to 'Sign In' , new_user_session_path%><br>`

`<%= link_to 'Sign Up' , new_user_registration_path%>`

So when I click on the Sign_in link. I get the following error.

> Errno::ENOENT in Devise::RegistrationsController#new
>   
>   No such file or directory - getcwd

There was a similar question asked before but did not solve my problem. This problem only started coming up recently and never occured when I used rails for my other apps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243548/no-such-file-or-directory-getcwd-error-on-rubygems-on-mac-os-lion

Answer (score 0):

did you generate the devise views?

```
rails generate devise:views
```