# errors with "gem list", "rails -v"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

On macOS High Sierra (10.13), 'gem list' returns the following error:

```
gem list
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:93:in `pwd': No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:93:in `lockfile_contents'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:81:in `lockfile_version'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:29:in `bundler_version_with_reason'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:12:in `bundler_version'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:46:in `compatible?'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1059:in `block in find_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1058:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1058:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1058:in `find_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:215:in `try_activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
    from :6:in `'
```

Current Ruby version:

```
$ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
```

Current Rails version:

```
$rails -v
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:93:in `pwd': No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:93:in `lockfile_contents'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:81:in `lockfile_version'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:29:in `bundler_version_with_reason'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:12:in `bundler_version'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:46:in `compatible?'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1059:in `block in find_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1058:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1058:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1058:in `find_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:215:in `try_activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
    from :6:in `'
```

Comment: try gem install bundler

Comment: Check [this quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243548/no-such-file-or-directory-getcwd-error-on-rubygems-on-mac-os-lion), it may help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Gerry's link above is the first result from googling the error...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243548/no-such-file-or-directory-getcwd-error-on-rubygems-on-mac-os-lion

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

gem uninstall rails

gem install rails -v 4.2