# Rake commands failing on cloned rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I removed my local rails directory and git cloned a new one from my git repo.
When I run the command rake db:seeds, I receive the following error.

```
...rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:58:in `pwd': No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)
```

I've run bundle and can't think of anything that would cause the error. I've searched for this issue but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+pwd+No+such+file+or+directory+getcwd+ENOENT

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by a background process that expects the directory to be in its place.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243548/no-such-file-or-directory-getcwd-error-on-rubygems-on-mac-os-lion

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Give that a try.

Comment: Well, we need error codes and more environment information. Your issue could be that you've removed the directory (try exiting the console and cd-ing back in). Your issue could be that this is a Vagrant project and you havent' added it back in. You maybe changed your environment and need to restart your bash session.

Comment: You should at least add some explanation to your answer about **why** that should be tried and how it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems something happened to the folder that you were working on, such as renaming, deleting, etc. Try closing your terminal window and `cd`ing back to the application folder, then re-run the `rake db:seed` command.