# Updated Mac to Catalina and ever since have had a Cocopods or Ruby error when runnings pod in workspace

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, cocoapods, macos-catalina

Its been a couple of weeks with this issue, I have tried everything and not sure what the issue could be and how I can solve it. I have deleted and reinstalled ruby, cocoapods, xcode tools, etc.  I am somewhat new to all of this and have looked at and tried to follow almost every similar forms that show similar issues to mine.

For some reason, if I run pod outside of my workspace folder everything works fine.  If I CD into any folder or try to create a new xcode project and run pod init I get the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    35: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    34: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    33: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
    32: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    31: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    30: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    29: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    28: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    27: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    26: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    25: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    24: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    23: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    22: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    21: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    19: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    18: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    17: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    16: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    15: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/i18n.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    13: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    12: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/i18n-0.9.5/lib/i18n.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    10: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     9: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/map.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     7: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/synchronization.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `load_native_extensions'
     4: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `each'
     3: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `block in load_native_extensions'
     2: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:62:in `try_load_c_extension'
     1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- concurrent/concurrent_ruby_ext (LoadError)
    46: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    45: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    44: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
    43: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    42: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    41: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    40: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    39: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    38: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    37: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    36: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    35: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    34: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    33: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    32: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    31: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    30: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    29: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    28: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    27: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    26: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/i18n.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    25: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    24: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    23: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/i18n-0.9.5/lib/i18n.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    21: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    20: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/map.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    18: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    17: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/synchronization.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `load_native_extensions'
    15: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `each'
    14: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `block in load_native_extensions'
    13: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.5/lib/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:62:in `try_load_c_extension'
    12: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
    11: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:123:in `rescue in require'
    10: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:213:in `try_activate'
     9: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1036:in `find_by_path'
     8: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1036:in `find'
     7: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1036:in `each'
     6: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1037:in `block in find_by_path'
     5: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:39:in `compatible?'
     4: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:7:in `bundler_version'
     3: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:22:in `bundler_version_with_reason'
     2: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:68:in `lockfile_version'
     1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `lockfile_contents'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `pwd': Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
```

Comment: Maybe the first answer here helps? It's the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243548/no-such-file-or-directory-getcwd-error-on-rubygems-on-mac-os-lion

Comment: Another explanation: http://pinter.org/archives/5662

Comment: How to update CocoaPods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481636/updating-to-latest-version-of-cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal. Execute the following in your terminal to get the latest stable version:

```sh
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Add `--pre` to get the latest pre release:

```sh
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```